# Converter linhas para colunas (Pivot?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com 33 milhões de registros de telefones com a estrutura abaixo:

```
ccpf_cnpj   ddd telefone    tipo    origem
11111111111 83  81021111    M   SERASA
11111111111 83  87472222    M   SERASA
11111111111 83  81023333    M   TRANSUNION
11111111111 83  88724444    M   TRANSUNION
11111111111 83  87475555    M   TRANSUNION
22222222222 43  36271111    F   SERASA
22222222222 44  36272222    F   SERASA
22222222222 43  36273333    F   TRANSUNION
22222222222 43  36284444    F   TRANSUNION
33333333333 51  51811111    F   SERASA
33333333333 51  56212222    F   SERASA
33333333333 51  96213333    M   SERASA
```

Preciso "desnormalizar" esta tabela de modo a cada CPF possuir um único registro, deve ficar assim:

```
CCPF_CNPJ   DDD_1   TELEFONE_1  TIPO_1  ORIGEM_1    DDD_2   TELEFONE_2  TIPO_2  ORIGEM_2    DDD_3   TELEFONE_3  TIPO_3  ORIGEM_3    DDD_4   TELEFONE_4  TIPO_4  ORIGEM_4    DDD_5   TELEFONE_5  TIPO_5  ORIGEM_5
11111111111 83  81021111    M   SERASA  83  87472222    M   SERASA  83  81023333    M   TRANSUNION  83  88724444    M   TRANSUNION  83  87475555    M   TRANSUNION
22222222222 43  36271111    F   SERASA  44  36272222    F   SERASA  43  36273333    F   TRANSUNION  43  36274444    F   TRANSUNION  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
33333333333 51  51811111    F   SERASA  51  56212222    F   SERASA  51  96213333    M   SERASA  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Um colega aqui sugeriu usar um Pivot + Unpivot, mas não consegui adequar à necessidade, ou talvez eu não saiba usar o Pivot para este caso, geralmente quando uso tenho um campo que me define as colunas, o que não é o caso.

Consegui fazer em uma amostragem (100 registros) usando joins com a própria tabela, mas a solução ficou inviável devido ao volume de dados (relembrando: 33 milhões de registros).

Alguém já passou por algo semelhante?

A versão do SQL Server aqui é a 2014.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez Consegui executar o código corrigindo dois detalhes, mas ao executar me retornou a mensagem 'An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.' após pouco mais de 5 minuitos de execução. Creio que o volume de dados esteja impactando mesmo. Vou tentar "quebrar" a tabela em partes menores para ver se consigo executar. Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu faria por faixas de CNPJ. Você tentou editar minha resposta, certo? Com a alteração a resposta funciona pra você?

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez  Agradeço imensamente a ajuda! Eu estava trabalhando pra dividir a tabela em partes menores, mas responderam minha pergunta no Stack overflow em inglês, testei a solução e funcionou (você tem razão, ele usou faixas, mas não foi necessário usar Pivot): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340101/rows-to-columns-pivot

Answer (score 2):

[Adaptei esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102114/2999) para a sua necessidade. Usa não apenas `PIVOT`, mas também construção dinâmica de query porque o número de colunas será indefinido:

```
DECLARE 
  @MaxCount INT, 
  @coluna_ddd CHAR(3) = 'ddd', @ddd NVARCHAR(MAX), 
  @coluna_telefone CHAR(8) = 'telefone', @telefone NVARCHAR(MAX), 
  @coluna_tipo CHAR(4) = 'tipo', @tipo NVARCHAR(MAX), 
  @coluna_origem CHAR(6) = 'origem', @origem NVARCHAR(MAX), 
  @colunas_dinamicas VARCHAR(MAX), @sentenca_pivot VARCHAR(MAX),
  @i INT, @j NVARCHAR(10)

SELECT @MaxCount = MAX(r), @i = 1 FROM (SELECT CCPF_CNPJ, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CCPF_CNPJORDER BY CCPF_CNPJ) r FROM Tabela) T
WHILE @i <= @MaxCount
    SELECT @j = cast(@i AS NVARCHAR(10)), 
           @ddd = COALESCE(@ddd + ', ', '') + '['+@coluna_ddd + '_' + @j + ']', 
           @telefone = COALESCE(@telefone + ', ', '') + '[' + @coluna_telefone + '_' + @j + ']', 
           @tipo = COALESCE(@tipo + ', ', '') + '[' + @tipo + '_' + @j + ']', 
           @origem = COALESCE(@origem + ', ', '') + '[' + @origem + '_' + @j + ']', 
           @colunas_dinamicas = COALESCE(@colunas_dinamicas + ', ', '') + '[' + @coluna_ddd + '_' + @j + '], [' + @coluna_telefone + '_' + @j + '], [' + @coluna_tipo + '_' + @j + '], [' + @coluna_origem + '_' + @j + ']', 
           @i = @i + 1

SELECT 
    @sentenca_pivot = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT CCPF_CNPJ, ''@2_'' + CAST(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CCPF_CNPJ ORDER BY CCPF_CNPJ) AS VARCHAR) A, @2 FROM Tabela) T PIVOT (MAX(@2) FOR A IN (@1)) PVT',
    @colunas_dinamicas = 'SELECT A1.CCPF_CNPJ, ' + @colunas_dinamicas +' FROM (' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@sentenca_pivot, '@1', @ddd), '@2', @coluna_ddd)+') A1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ('+REPLACE(REPLACE(@sentenca_pivot, '@1', @telefone), '@2', @coluna_telefone)+') A2 ON A1.CCPF_CNPJ = A2.CCPF_CNPJ
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ('+REPLACE(REPLACE(@sentenca_pivot, '@1', @tipo), '@2', @coluna_tipo)+') A3 ON A1.CCPF_CNPJ = A3.CCPF_CNPJ
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ('+REPLACE(REPLACE(@sentenca_pivot, '@1', @origem), '@2', @coluna_origem)+') A4 ON A1.CCPF_CNPJ = A4.CCPF_CNPJ'

EXEC(@colunas_dinamicas)
```

Comment: @CassioVeras a edição que você fez altera, mesmo que um detalhe pequeno, a resposta do Cigano Morrison. Para estes casos, é recomendado que você avise via comentários e peça que o autor efetue a alteração, pois edições não podem alterar o sentido da resposta/pergunta, ou adicionar informações que causem isso.

Comment: @Diego Felipe Ok. O código que ele colocou não funciona como está publicado, realmente são apenas dois detalhes. Sou novo aqui, vou comentar a resposta dele então. Grato.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Campo1,Exemplo1,Exemplo2,Exemplo3
FROM
(
select Campo1,Campo2,'Exemplo' +convert(varchar(10),ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by Campo1 Order By Campo2)) as Sequencia from Tabela1

)Apelido1
PIVOT
(
MAX(Campo2)
for Sequencia in (Exemplo1,Exemplo2,Exemplo3)
)Apelido2
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha, isso aqui funciona. Neste caso estou assumindo que ficara o CPF que tenha o telefone de maior numero, se você tiver outra coluna que faça mais sentido é só trocar:

```
FILTRO = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CCPF_CNPJ order by **TELEFONE** desc),
```

por:

```
FILTRO = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CCPF_CNPJ order by **ID** desc),
```

ou

```
FILTRO = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CCPF_CNPJ order by **DATA** desc),
```

etc...

```
WITH DADOS AS(  
 SELECT   
     FILTRO = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CCPF_CNPJ order by TELEFONE desc),   
     CCPF_CNPJ,   
     DDD,   
     TELEFONE,   
     TIPO,   
     ORIGEM  
 FROM TABELA
)  
SELECT * FROM DADOS
WHERE FILTRO = 1
```